# How do I use LSTMCell and RNN in keras to manually unroll a LSTM layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

For an experiment I'm currently doing, I have to access the hidden states and the output at each time step dynamically and make changes to them based on a condition before they are passed on to the next time step.

So I want to loop and manually unroll an LSTM layer for learning and can't use the LSTM functionality readily available in Keras.

```
# The code should look something like this:

input_layer = Input(shape = (time_steps, embedding_size))
cell = LSTMCell(units = hidden_units)
recurrent_layer = RNN(cell, return_states = True, return_sequences = True)

states = [tf.zeros(hidden_units, dtype = tf.float32)]*2

for time_step in time_steps:
    cell_outputs = recurrent_layer(input = input_layer[:, time_step, :], states = states)
    cell_output, states = cell_outputs[0], cell_outputs[1:]

    # check cell_output, make changes
    cell_output = tamper_celloutput(cell_output)
    final_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(cell_output)

myModel = Model(input_layer, final_output)
```

Also when I try the above code, I get errors with respect to size and dimensions of the inputs.
Tried debugging and restructuring several times.

I can't post my whole code. Any help, changes, and suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does `tamper_celloutput` do?

Comment: Its a function to change values of the tensor based on a condition using tf.where. It doesn't matter even if I remove it for now. I'm trying to make the looping work